# Get consecutive nodes with following-sibling and condition

Tags: xml, recursion, xslt, xpath

My XML file looks like this, but bigger:

```
<w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>grande</forme><lemme>grand</lemme><categorie>ADJFS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>douleur</forme><lemme>douleur</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>père</forme><lemme>père</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>duchesne</forme><lemme>duchesne</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>exemple.</forme><lemme>exemple.</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>
<!-- ... -->
```

I would like to get every `<w>` node recursively to get words to create sentences with.
For example, the final word here is `"exemple."`. So I would like to get every `<forme>` until `.`
to generate a sentence.

For now I can only match the node with the full stop. I don't know how to select the first `<w>` node (first word of the sentence) until the last `<w>` node (final word).

```
following-sibling::w[contains(forme, '.')][1]
```

My goal is to select every `<w>` node (or `<forme>`) until the word with the full stop, and recursively.

I started to write a template to concatenate strings:

```
<xsl:template name="concat">
  <xsl:param name="liste" />
  <xsl:param name="result" select="''"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$liste">
        <xsl:call-template name="concat">
          <xsl:with-param name="liste" select="$liste[position() &gt; 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="result" select="concat($result, ' ', $liste[1])" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$result" disable-output-escaping="no" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thx for the help. It's very important.

Comment: So the `.` after a word marks the end of a sentence. But how do you recognize the beginning?

Comment: Also please tell which XSLT processor you're using for this.

Comment: Recursively. The absolute first w node is the beginning of the first sentence. Maybe my way to achieve this task is not good.

Comment: xsltproc why ? and XSLT 1.0

Comment: Because the solution depends on the capabilities of your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use an `<xsl:key>` in the following way.

Keys let you index nodes by a certain property, for example you could index all nodes by some attribute value. But you could also index them by a calculated value.

In your case you have many `<w>` nodes like this:

```
<doc>                                                                              <!-- Sentence # -->
  <w><forme>le</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w>           <!-- 0 -->
  <w><forme>grand</forme><lemme>grand</lemme><categorie>ADJFS</categorie></w>      <!-- 0 -->
  <w><forme>test.</forme><lemme>test.</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>       <!-- 0 -->
  <w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w>           <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>grande</forme><lemme>grand</lemme><categorie>ADJFS</categorie></w>     <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>douleur</forme><lemme>douleur</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w>   <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w>           <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>père</forme><lemme>père</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>         <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>duchesne</forme><lemme>duchesne</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w> <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>exemple.</forme><lemme>exemple.</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w> <!-- 1 -->
  <w><forme>phrase</forme><lemme>phrase</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>     <!-- 2 -->
  <w><forme>suivante</forme><lemme>suivante</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w> <!-- 2 -->
</doc>
```

The ones with the full stop demarcate a sentence end. The preceding siblings up to the previous full stop are words of the same sentence.

We could say: *"All words belong to the same sentence that are preceded by the same number of full stops."*

The numbers in the comments above represent exactly that number. We can calculate it with `count(preceding-sibling::w[substring(forme, string-length(forme), 1) = '.'])`. And we can create an `<xsl:key>` that indexes `<w>` nodes by this number.

And then it's a matter of going over each node that marks a sentence end and using `key()` to retrieve all the `<w>` nodes that belong to the same sentence:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key
    name="kSentence"
    match="w"
    use="count(preceding-sibling::w[substring(forme, string-length(forme), 1) = '.'])"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <sentences>
      <xsl:for-each select="w[substring(forme, string-length(forme), 1) = '.']">
        <xsl:variable
          name="sentenceNum"
          select="count(preceding-sibling::w[substring(forme, string-length(forme), 1) = '.'])"
        />
        <sentence>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('kSentence', $sentenceNum)/lemme" />
        </sentence>      
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sentences>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives this result:

```
<sentences>
  <sentence>
    <lemme>le</lemme>
    <lemme>grand</lemme>
    <lemme>test.</lemme>
  </sentence>
  <sentence>
    <lemme>le</lemme>
    <lemme>grand</lemme>
    <lemme>douleur</lemme>
    <lemme>du</lemme>
    <lemme>père</lemme>
    <lemme>duchesne</lemme>
    <lemme>exemple.</lemme>
  </sentence>
</sentences>
```

The "phrase suivante" is not part of the result because it did not end with a full stop in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Either use classical sibling recursion where you in the template matching the parent/container node of the `w` siblings start with `<xsl:apply-templates select="w[1]"/>` and then process `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w[1]"><xsl:with-param name="previous-ws" select="$previous-ws | ."/></xsl:apply-templates/>` and have two template matches for e.g. `<xsl:template match="w[not(substring(forme, string-length(forme)) = '.')]">` and `<xsl:template match="w[substring(forme, string-length(forme)) = '.']">` or use a key `<xsl:key name="siblings" match="w[not(substring(forme, string-length(forme)) = '.')]" use="generate-id(following-sibling::w[substring(forme, string-length(forme)) = '.'][1])"/>`, then process all `<xsl:apply-templates select="w[substring(forme, string-length(forme)) = '.']"/>` and in the template matching `w` you can collect the preceding siblings simply with `key('siblings', generate-id())`.

Comment: Thx Martin for your response. Could you be more understandable for me ? I know templates but i have no idea about key(). I'm sure you response is great but i don't undestand it. I prefer manager RAX, RBX, RCX registers... This task is so hard. Furthermore there are . in middle of two words. For exemple, one word can appear like this : "about. his" and i need to do the correct html layout with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:fer each group` with `group-ending-with`.

There are several methods to accomplish the same thing in XSLT 1.0 - among them "sibling recursion" or using a *key* to link each word to its nearest following sibling that ends with a period (both of these have been mentioned by Martin Honnen in his answer above).

The method you have attempted, using a recursive named template, is also an option. Here is a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <word>Joe</word>
    <word>waited</word>
    <word>for</word>
    <word>train.</word>
    <word>The</word>
    <word>train</word>
    <word>was</word>
    <word>late.</word>
    <word>Mary</word>
    <word>and</word>
    <word>Samantha</word>
    <word>took</word>
    <word>the</word>
    <word>bus.</word>
    <word>Orphan</word>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="combine-words">
            <xsl:with-param name="words" select="word"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="combine-words">
    <xsl:param name="words" />
    <xsl:param name="accumulated" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:if test="$words">
        <xsl:variable name="word" select="$words[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="isLast" select="substring($word, string-length($word), 1)='.'" />
        <xsl:if test="$isLast">
            <sentence>
                <xsl:for-each select="$accumulated | $word">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sentence>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="combine-words">
            <xsl:with-param name="words" select="$words[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="accumulated" select="$accumulated[not($isLast)] | $word[not($isLast)]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <sentence>Joe waited for train.</sentence>
   <sentence>The train was late.</sentence>
   <sentence>Mary and Samantha took the bus.</sentence>
</output>
```

Comment: Thx Michael for your answer. It works but i need to produce an html layout and i struggle with that. Furthermore there are . in middle of two words. For exemple, one word can appear like this : "about. his" and i need to do the correct html layout with that. Thx again

Comment: What would be the version for XLST 2.0 ? I'm just curious

Comment: @EtienneArmangau Regarding HTML, I believe you should be able to do the necessary adaption by yourself. Regarding a period in the middle, please post a new question with this new problem - and make sure to clarify what the correct result is in such case.