# I would to do a recursive template with following sibling

Tags: xml, recursion, xslt, xslt-2.0

I work on an NLP projet and i need to do some things. First of all, i work on an xml file like that. I precise that i started to learn XSLT one week ago so please be understanding with me. I'm lost but i've read tons posts on stackoverflow with recursion and following sibling, recursion in XSLT but i didn't find the answer to my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="duchn_question2.xsl"?>
<cordial2xml>
<w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>grande</forme><lemme>grand</lemme><categorie>ADJFS</categorie></w><w><forme>douleur</forme><lemme>douleur</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>père</forme><lemme>père</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>duchesne</forme><lemme>duchesne</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>au sujet de</forme><lemme>au sujet de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>mort</forme><lemme>mort</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>marat</forme><lemme>marat</lemme><categorie>NPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>assassiné</forme><lemme>assassiner</lemme><categorie>VPARPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>à</forme><lemme>à</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>coups</forme><lemme>coup</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>couteau</forme><lemme>couteau</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>par</forme><lemme>par</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>une</forme><lemme>un</lemme><categorie>DETIFS</categorie></w><w><forme>garce</forme><lemme>gars</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>calvados</forme><lemme>calvados</lemme><categorie>NCMIN</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
<w><forme>dont</forme><lemme>dont</lemme><categorie>PRI</categorie></w><w><forme>l'</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>évêque</forme><lemme>évêque</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>fauchet</forme><lemme>fauchet</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>était</forme><lemme>être</lemme><categorie>VINDI3S</categorie></w><w><forme>le</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>directeur.ses</forme><lemme>directeur.ses</lemme><categorie>NCI</categorie></w>
<w><forme>bons</forme><lemme>bon</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>avis</forme><lemme>avis</lemme><categorie>NCMIN</categorie></w><w><forme>aux</forme><lemme>au</lemme><categorie>DETDPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>braves</forme><lemme>brave</lemme><categorie>NCPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>sans</forme><lemme>sans</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>-culottes</forme><lemme>culotte</lemme><categorie>NCFP</categorie></w><w><forme>pour</forme><lemme>pour</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>qu'</forme><lemme>que</lemme><categorie>SUB</categorie></w><w><forme>ils</forme><lemme>il</lemme><categorie>PPER3P</categorie></w><w><forme>se</forme><lemme>se</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>tiennent</forme><lemme>tenir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3P</categorie></w><w><forme>sur</forme><lemme>sur</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>leurs</forme><lemme>leur</lemme><categorie>DETPOSS</categorie></w><w><forme>gardes</forme><lemme>garde</lemme><categorie>NCFP</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
<w><forme>attendu qu'</forme><lemme>attendu que</lemme><categorie>SUB</categorie></w><w><forme>il</forme><lemme>il</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>y</forme><lemme>y</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>a</forme><lemme>avoir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3S</categorie></w><w><forme>dans</forme><lemme>dans</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>paris</forme><lemme>pari</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>plusieurs</forme><lemme>plusieurs</lemme><categorie>ADJIND</categorie></w><w><forme>milliers</forme><lemme>millier</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>tondus</forme><lemme>tondu</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>vendée</forme><lemme>vendée</lemme><categorie>NPFS</categorie></w><w><forme>qui</forme><lemme>qui</lemme><categorie>PRI</categorie></w><w><forme>ont</forme><lemme>avoir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3P</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>patte</forme><lemme>patte</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>graissée</forme><lemme>graisser</lemme><categorie>VPARPFS</categorie></w><w><forme>pour</forme><lemme>pour</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>égorger</forme><lemme>égorger</lemme><categorie>VINF</categorie></w><w><forme>tous</forme><lemme>tout</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>les</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>bons</forme><lemme>bon</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>citoyens</forme><lemme>citoyen</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>.</forme><lemme>.</lemme><categorie>PCTFORTE</categorie></w>
<w><forme>marat</forme><lemme>marat</lemme><categorie>NPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>n'</forme><lemme>ne</lemme><categorie>ADV</categorie></w><w><forme>est</forme><lemme>être</lemme><categorie>VINDP3S</categorie></w><w><forme>plus</forme><lemme>plus</lemme><categorie>ADV</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w><w><forme>foutre.peuple</forme><lemme>foutre.peuple</lemme><categorie>NCI</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w><w><forme>gémis</forme><lemme>gémir</lemme><categorie>VPARPMP</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
```

I would like to get each w nodes from the beginning of a sentence until the w node which child forme contains '.' (end of sentence). And i would like to do that for every sentence in my xml doc.
I know how to grab the first w nodes from the begenning until point. By the way i would like to have to following-sibling w node of the last node in my xpath request to have the w node with forme with '.' in.

```
//w[not(contains(./forme, '.'))][following-sibling::*[1][contains(./forme, '.')]]
```

If i have the following sibling, the first, after [contains(./forme, '.')], i have an entire sentence with my w nodes. I have this code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
  
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <html>
      <h1>Poème du Père Duchesne</h1>
      <body>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="//w[not(contains(./forme, '.'))][following-sibling::*[1][contains(./forme, '.')]]"/></p>
      </body>
    </html>
    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that i capture only the first w nodes. I need to find a method th apply that recursively. Now i have only this output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <h1>Poème du Père Duchesne</h1>
   <body>
<p>leleDETDMS citoyenscitoyenNCMP ,,PCTFAIB laleDETDFS dedePREP horriblehorribleADJSIG
      parlerparlerVINF entendreentendreVINF secourssecoursNCMIN alorsalorsADV obtenirobtenirVINF
      fersferNCMP sonsonDETPOSS aussiaussiADV estêtreVINDP3S guerreguerreNCFS respectéerespecterVPARPFS
      populairepopulaireADJSIG quelquesquelqueADJIND criminelscriminelADJMP guillotineguillotineNCFS
      dedePREP ttePPER2S aitavoirVSUBP3S laleDETDFS laleDETDFS canonscanonNCMP touttoutADV
      véritablevéritableADJSIG laleDETDFS meilleuremeilleurADJFS égorgéégorgerVPARPMS gloiregloireNCFS
      tontonNCMS pitiépitiéNCFS cetteceDETDEM assignatsassignatNCMP auauDETDMS auxauDETDPIG
      citoyenscitoyenNCMP leursleurDETPOSS roiroiNCMS foutrefoutreVINF</p>
   </body>
</html
```

so, only the first sentence and i don't have have the last w node furthermore.
I would like to get this output result for each sentence and not the first only one. How to do that? With recursive template ?
Thx

Comment: Is there any difference to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034123/get-consecutive-nodes-with-following-sibling-and-condition? Did none of the answers help?

Comment: No because here i will need the categorie nodes so i need to have w nodes, not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do this with sibling recursion, but it's easier to do it using `<xsl:for-each-group>`. Something like:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="w" group-ending-with="w[forme='.']">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/forme" separator=" "/></p>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```